# Running php scripts through html forms located in other directory

Tags: php, wamp, forms

I installed wamp in a directory

```
E:\folder_name\wamp
```

it has all the stuff www and PHP files example testmysql.php in it and it works fine when I run 
it on the browser directly via

`http://localhost:80/testmysql.php`

I am working on a project and  created a file in directory E:\folder_name\index.html  and this index.html has a form

```
<form method="post" action="../wamp/www/testmysql.php">

/*
 *  form inputs etc here and submitt button also 
*
*

</form>
```

when I run it in the browser it downloads the PHP file instead of executing it.
for PHP script I m using phpstorm 
Plz help me

Comment: Put your projects in a subfolder of `\wamp\www\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change address in action to:

```
http://localhost/testmysql.php
```

Comment: fully qualified URL is not necessary, [relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477128/7926064) work equally well and is even more portable

Comment: i know.but this answer for this question.he has form outside of server(wamp/www) folder for this he must use fully URL

Answer (score 1):

The folder in your index.html is relative to what your webserver serves so it should be

```
<form method="post" action="testmysql.php">
```

if the folder structure is like this

- `E:\folder_name\wamp\www\index.html`
- `E:\folder_name\wamp\www\testmysql.php`

Comment: Small note: You should never put anything in `\wamp\www\` that folder is reserved for WAMPServer code. Add a subfolder to `www` for each project. Better still add a Virtual Host as well

Comment: sure and what's a Virtual Host ?

Comment: you can find yuor answer  about Virtual Host trough  this link http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2014/how-setup-virtual-hosts-wamp